# Finding a mistake in elementary mathematics

Tags: complex-numbers

Assume that by $i$ we mean $\sqrt{-1}$. We know that 
$$
1-i=\sqrt{2}\, e^{{\Large\frac{7\pi}{4}i}} \tag{1}
$$

Now I want to obtain the value of $1-i$ by elementary mathematics, but I do not know where I made a mistake such that the final result does not match with ($1$).
$$
1-i=\sqrt{(1-i)^2}=\sqrt{1-1-2i}=\sqrt{-2i}=\sqrt{2}\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{i}
=\sqrt{2}ii^{1/2}=\sqrt{2}i^{3/2}
$$
Moreover, we know that $i=e^{\Large{\frac{\pi}{2}i}}$. Therefore, we get
$$
1-i=\sqrt{2}\, e^{\Large{\frac{3\pi}{4}i}} \tag{2}
$$

Comment: The square root involves two branches... You introduced an extra solution by squaring, then picked the incorrect branch of the square root.

Comment: You have to be careful with square roots: in general, when you write $\sqrt a$, what do you mean?

Comment: Your first step is not valid. It is essentially the same as writing $$-1 = \sqrt{(-1)^2}=\sqrt{1}=1$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sqrt{(1-i)^2}=\pm(1-i)=\begin{cases}\sqrt2e^{3\pi i/4}&\text{if }-\\\sqrt2 e^{7\pi i/4}&\text{if }+\end{cases}$$ Your first step does not hold, $(1-i)$ is not the only square root of $(1-i)^2$. By similar reasoning, we could get, say $$-i=\sqrt{(-i)^2}=\sqrt{-1}=i$$

Comment: Is it possible to ask you to explain more. Thanks.

Comment: @user0410 essentially, while $1-i$ is _a_ square root of $-2i$, so is $-1+i$ - there isn't a unique square root. This is why it is wrong to write that $1-i=\sqrt{(1-i)^2}$, and so using this can easily give you a false result (as it does here). The issue with your method is that there are always two square roots of any complex number, and you ended up picking the wrong one. You had a $\sqrt{-1}$ in your calculation. This could have been either $i$ or $-i$, you chose $i$, but there was no reason for excluding $-i$. You have to be very careful with square roots of complex numbers.

Comment: Thanks got it. All of the time  radical questions confused me. Thanks again